# How can I keep the variable to be used to compare

Tags: c++

Hello im not sure how I can keep the variable lets say `lastWordLoaded` and then use this to compare with the next word being loaded in the dictionary which would be `word`..

I have a method `compareWords` that will print out -1 if the lastWordLoaded > CurrentWord, thus this would mean its not in alphabetical order, if lastWordLoaded < CurrentWord it will print 0, thus if 0 the file is in alphabetical order. Though I'm unsure how I can retreive the `lastWordLoaded` to be used in this situation.

```
Dictionary::Dictionary() {
    //check if the file was opened
    if (dictionaryFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(dictionaryFile, word) &&
            getline(dictionaryFile, definition) &&
            getline(dictionaryFile, type) &&
            getline(dictionaryFile, blank)) {

                    myWords[wordCount] = fromRecord(word, definition, type);
                    if (compareWords(word, lastWordLoaded) != 0)
                    {
                        cout << "\nThe dictionary isnt in alphabetical order." << endl;
                        cout << "Error at word = " << getWordCount() << endl;
                        system("Pause");
                    }
        }
        //close the file
        dictionaryFile.close();     
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make it easier for us, keep it concise and post just the part of the code?

Comment: cleaned it up, sorry.

Comment: Why can't you just do "else lastWordLoaded = word;"

Comment: Will that work for my scenario?

Comment: How have you declared word? If it is a std::string, it should work.

Comment: Pretty sure its std::string, ill test it out see how it goes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about keeping the `lastWordLoaded` in a variable and updating it at the end of the cycle like this:

```
string lastWordLoaded = "";
while (getline(dictionaryFile, word) &&
        getline(dictionaryFile, definition) &&
        getline(dictionaryFile, type) &&
        getline(dictionaryFile, blank)) {

                myWords[wordCount] = fromRecord(word, definition, type);
                if (compareWords(word, lastWordLoaded) != 0)
                {
                    cout << "\nThe dictionary isnt in alphabetical order." << endl;
                    cout << "Error at word = " << getWordCount() << endl;
                    system("pause");
                }
                lastWordLoaded = word;
    }
```